# Combine Observables with latest of any one and previous value of the other observables

Tags: rxjs, observable, combinelatest

Let say I have observables A, B, C. I have to listen to change of these three and alter a caculation.

i.e., On value change on any one of the obseravable, I need to recalculate with the new value from the present and the old value for the rest of the observables.

I tried to use combineLatest, which was perfect except the first behavior that all the observables should have a latest/change in the value.

Comment: That's what `combineLatest` does already. But first, all source Observables have to to emit at least one value.

Comment: I am looking for an option that can handle without all the observables emit the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just prefix each source Observable with `startWith` operator before passing them into `combineLatest`:

```
combineLatest(
  obsA$.pipe(startWith(null)),
  obsB$.pipe(startWith(null)),
  obsC$.pipe(startWith(null)),
)
```

Then you'll have to check manually what values are `null`.

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution I was looking for, In my situation, Instead of null I passed in the existing/default value that I could use and it works like a charm!